# Android market filter out tablets

Tags: android, eclipse, screen, tablet

I have scoured the internet for this answer, and I feel like I keep getting close to it but then it turns out to not be quite what I want.  If someone posts a quick link that specifies exactly what I need I will be quite disappointed in myself...

I am making an Android app whose minimum api is 4 and android version is 1.6.  It works on tablets, but it is not optimized quite yet, so when I publish it I do not want tablets to be able to find it at all.  I have read the support screens android pages about adding this code to my manifest:

```
<supports-screens 
     android:smallScreens="true"
     android:normalScreens="true"
     android:largeScreens="true"
     android:xLargeScreens="false"
                  />
```

That particular code ( android:xLargeScreens="false") is not supported with android 1.6, so I cannot add that to my manifest.  The definition of each screen is pretty vague as well... for instance, the large screen size is defined as "a screen that is significantly larger than a "normal" handset screen".  Does that mean the largeScreens are tablets as well?  Do I need to set that to false??

So since that is not an option, and knowing my specs... how *do* I filter my app in the android market so that it does not show up for tablets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. AFAIK, it is impossible to close that xlargescreen possibility - you have set the problem correctly.
2. Don't be afraid of all tablets - there are very many cheaper ones that have screen smaller than that of modern phones.
3. Don't be afraid of greater tablets, too. Their owners are accustomed that SW for elder than APK 9 versions are not optimized for their devices. It couldn't be.

Edit:
cite from the [android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHandsetApps):

> Caution: If you use the `<supports-screens>` element for the reverse
>   scenario (when your application is not compatible with larger screens)
>   and set the larger screen size attributes to "false", then external
>   services such as Android Market do not apply filtering. Your
>   application will still be available to larger screens, but when it
>   runs, it will not resize to fit the screen. Instead, the system will
>   emulate a handset screen size (about 320dp x 480dp; see [Screen
>   Compatibility Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) for more information). If you want to prevent your
>   application from being downloaded on larger screens, use
>   `<compatible-screens>`, as discussed in the previous section about
>   [Declaring an App is Only for Handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHandsetApps).

Comment: This seems to be the tough love answer.  I do intend to make my app flow seamlessly for tablets...at a later date.  I was hoping I could cut it off of the tablet market for the time being, but it is sounding like I just simply cannot?

Comment: You see, everyone who makes such app for weaker and older phones whants to block out the larger tablets, with real Xlarge screens, because on 1.6 we can't support it at all. But I never heard of somebody who managed it. Me too. And attention! setting somescreen support to false makes you app to use the compatibility mode for it. So, it will look even worse.

Comment: I've found a cite from docs - it's really impossible and the results of trying will look badly. Or try to set by densities and numbers - look the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is remove the screen support for big screens.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

So that the market would know your app is only compatible on certain screens.

Comment: Right, that is what I am asking in my question though... Android v 1.6 does not support using the xLargeScreens support-screen attribute.  So does settinge largeScreens="false" take care of all tablets then, or will that restrict phones?